# How to fade in an element when its scrolled towards center of page

Tags: css, reactjs

I would like an element to fade in when I scroll down a page and the element is vertically towards center of page. I want to make use of window.scrollY to make this work. Whats the best way to achieve this in ReactJS?

Comment: Please show us what code you have tried - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and could you say why you want to use scrollY as opposed to IntersectionObserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const FadeInOnScroll = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const onScroll = () => {
      const element = document.getElementById("myElement");

      if (element) {
        const elementPosition = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        const screenPosition = window.innerHeight / 2;

        if (elementPosition < screenPosition) {
          setVisible(true);
        }
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      id="myElement"
      className={`fade-in ${visible ? "is-visible" : ""}`}
      style={{ opacity: visible ? 1 : 0 }}
    >
      {/* Your content goes here */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default FadeInOnScroll;
```